# How to output the count of all pairwise combination of two binary columns from a Spark dataframe even when it is zero count?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to output the count of all pairwise combination of two binary(0/1) columns from a Spark dataframe even when the count is zero?

```
final_sdf.groupBy('actual', 'prediction').count().show()
```

Current output is

[image: Current]

But my desired output includes the zero groups as below.

[image: Desired]

Comment: does the `prediction` field in the `final_sdf` have rows with `0`?

Comment: No @samkart. There is no rows of prediction=0.

Comment: then do you require to insert dummy rows with the zeroes? because group by will group based on values already present.

Comment: I will try to create a spark dataframe because I've calculated the count for each pairwise combination by filtering. Thanks @samkart for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the idea to do this, is first create the missing binary rows, allocate value count to 0, filter, then append the dataset.

Let's assume our main dataset is called `df` and looks as below:

```
+------+----------+-----+
|actual|prediction|count|
+------+----------+-----+
|1     |1.0       |944  |
|0     |1.0       |208  |
+------+----------+-----+
```

First, let's create a column called `array` for example with value `abs(actual - 1)`, this way, we get the missing binary value. Then, we explode that back to prediction and we drop our `array` column.

```
val df2 = df1
  .withColumn("array", array(col("actual"), abs(col("actual") - 1)))
  .withColumn("prediction", explode(col("array")))
  .drop("array")
```

```
+------+----------+-----+
|actual|prediction|count|
+------+----------+-----+
|1     |1         |944  |
|1     |0         |944  |
|0     |0         |208  |
|0     |1         |208  |
+------+----------+-----+
```

Then we do an `anti` join (`df1` and `df2`) and overwrite `count` value with 0.

```
val df3 = df2.join(df1, Seq("actual", "prediction", "count"), "anti")
  .withColumn("count", lit(0))
```

```
+------+----------+-----+
|actual|prediction|count|
+------+----------+-----+
|1     |0         |0    |
|0     |0         |0    |
+------+----------+-----+
```

Finally, we union these two dataframes:

```
df1.union(df3).show(10)
```

```
+------+----------+-----+
|actual|prediction|count|
+------+----------+-----+
|     1|       1.0|  944|
|     0|       1.0|  208|
|     1|       0.0|    0|
|     0|       0.0|    0|
+------+----------+-----+
```

which is I hope what you need!

Comment: Thanks @vilalabinot for your solution. I have solved it by creating a Spark dataframe with the counts obtained through the filter function for every pairwise combination.